# Opencover branch percentage always 0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, report, code-coverage, opencover

I am working on Visual studio 2019 solution in C#, and i try to do the code coverage. It seems to be everything ok, but Branch coverage is always 0%. However it is possible to see that many branches are anywas visited. Someone with same problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the reportgenerator to the last version.